# Creating a table in LaTex with the following style

Tags: tables

I'm new to `LaTex`, and would like to create a table that looks as follows:

[image]

How can this be done in `LaTex`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need a blank table, this can be the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
&&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can get cells that span two columns with the `\multicolumn` command, e.g., `\multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading}`. Vertical lines you put in the format, horizontal lines in the content:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 r1c1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{r1c2-3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{r1c4-5} \\
\hline
 etc.
 \end{tabular}
```

However, before you go any further with this, I *strongly* advise you to read the introduction to the [documentation](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) for the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package. It'll tell you how you should *really* lay out your table.