# Problem with making table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have been in a problem with making a table in LaTeX as attached in the figure below. Please help me out.

[image: Table]

I am trying like:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{Input Values} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Output Values} \\
\hline
1&2&The values  \\
\hline
3&5&\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
      1 & 2 &  &  &  \\
      \hline
       & &  &  &  \\
      &  &  &  &  \\
       &  &  &  &  \\
       &  &  &  &  \\
       &  &  &  &  \\
       &  &  &  &  \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But not coming.

I am new to the latex  so please help me.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem with it?

Comment: Where do you have problems? Can you show us you tries in form of a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)? Btw: you should have a look at package `booktabs`.

Comment: @str  i am unable to make tha latex code for the table of the type as shown in the figure,

Comment: @str I am unable to divide the column in middle. I am using multirow code but it is not working

Comment: A `\multirow` is for distributing a cell over multiple *rows*, you want to distribute some cells over two *columns*, so you need `\multicolumn`. It is always nice if you show us the code that you already tried, a minimal (non-)working example.

Comment: Your attachment shows multicolumns, not multirows. Also, please read and follow Johannes' comment.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148898/ for an example.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. actually i am new to latex. can you give me the code for the blank table as shown in fig.

Comment: Take a look at the question I linked to in my previous comment, that has a similar table to the one you want.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I was trying like:  \begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{Input Values} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Output Values} \\
\hline
1&2&The values  \\
\hline
3&5&\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
      1 & 2 &  &  &  \\
      \hline
       & &  &  &  \\
      &  &  &  &  \\
       &  &  &  &  \\
       &  &  &  &  \\
       &  &  &  &  \\
       &  &  &  &  \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
 \end{tabular}  but it is not cominf

Comment: @Curious -- This is starting point.\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|} \hline \multicolumn{2}{|c}{Date with place} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Time} \\ \hline 
21/01&x&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{The data for different time}\\ \hline
22/01&y & sunday &233  \\ \hline
& & &  \\ \hline
& & &  \\ \hline
& & &  \\ \hline
& & &  \\ \hline
& & &  \\ \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}

Comment: Don't try to nest one tabular within another. Although you have five vertical lines, you only want four *columns* so instead of specifying |c|c|c|c|c|, you will want |c|c|c|c|. (You may not want to use c which will centre the text in the column. Your example suggests l might be a better choice since mostly you want stuff left-aligned. To get the centred headings, you can use \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{This Heading} which will centre just that entry over the two columns it spans.) And see the booktabs package documentation for an explanation of why you shouldn't want vertical lines at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Approach 1

Your table with `p{...}` columns of fixed width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Date with place} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Output Values}              \\
    \hline
    21/01 & x                             & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{The data for different day} \\
    \hline
    22/01 & y                             & sunday & 233                                    \\
    \hline
    23/01 & z                             & Mon    & 233                                    \\
    \hline
    24/01 & p                             & tues   & 134                                    \\
    \hline
    25/01 & q                             & wed    & 76                                     \\
    \hline
    26/01 & r                             & thurs  & 35                                     \\
    \hline
    27/01 & s                             & fi     & 87                                     \\
    \hline
    28/01 & t                             & sat    & 7                                      \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

## Approach 2

Using `booktabs` without the "sudoku grid" and `p{...}` columns of fixed width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Date with place} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Output Values}              \\
    \midrule
    21/01 & x                           & \multicolumn{2}{c}{The data for different day} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
    22/01 & y                           & sunday & 233                                   \\
    23/01 & z                           & Mon    & 233                                   \\
    24/01 & p                           & tues   & 134                                   \\
    25/01 & q                           & wed    & 76                                    \\
    26/01 & r                           & thurs  & 35                                    \\
    27/01 & s                           & fi     & 87                                    \\
    28/01 & t                           & sat    & 7                                     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

## Approach 3

Using `booktabs` and scalable columns as in `l`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Date with place} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Output Values}              \\
    \midrule
    21/01 & x                           & \multicolumn{2}{c}{The data for different day} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
    22/01 & y                           & sunday & 233                                   \\
    23/01 & z                           & Mon    & 233                                   \\
    24/01 & p                           & tues   & 134                                   \\
    25/01 & q                           & wed    & 76                                    \\
    26/01 & r                           & thurs  & 35                                    \\
    27/01 & s                           & fi     & 87                                    \\
    28/01 & t                           & sat    & 7                                     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

## Approach 4

**Inception** tables, a table inside a table!

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    Date with place & Output Values \\
    \midrule
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        21/01 & x \\
        22/01 & y \\
        23/01 & z \\
        24/01 & p \\
        25/01 & q \\
        26/01 & r \\
        27/01 & s \\
        28/01 & t \\
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{The data for different day} \\
        \midrule
        sunday & 233                                   \\
        Mon    & 233                                   \\
        tues   & 134                                   \\
        wed    & 76                                    \\
        thurs  & 35                                    \\
        fi     & 87                                    \\
        sat    & 7                                     \\
    \end{tabular}
    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]